# Apache WSGI vs. Django Development Server

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I recently decided to deploy my Django project using Apache and mod_WSGI. So, whereas my dev server runs on `localhost:8000`, my "Apache WSGI" server runs on `localhost`.

Everything looked good until I tried to POST to my Django REST API. For whatever reason, I can post perfectly fine to the Django dev server, but I cannot post to the Apache WSGI server.

As a matter of fact, I do not even see that a POST attempt was logged when I look at my Apache logs--I can see url errors there (when  I purposefully try to go to a page that doesn't exist for example) but no failed POST attempts.  What can be causing this problem and how can I troubleshoot it?

Could it be that the Django REST Framework is incompatible with WSGI? I am puzzled why everything else: admin page, logins, navigation, update views, forms, etc, work perfectly fine but this one thing is not even showing up in the logs.

EDIT: This is my virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    Alias /static /home/pi/myapp/myapp2/myapp/static    
    <Directory /home/pi/myapp/myapp2/myapp/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/pi/myapp/myapp2/myapp/myapp>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-path=/home/pi/myapp/myapp2/myapp python-home=/home/pi/WebApp/p3
    WSGIProcessGroup myapp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pi/myapp/myapp2/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: By Apache config, do you mean the virtual host file? How can that be the problem if virtually everything else is working as expected (just as it does on the dev server)?

Comment: Edited, it is now up.

Comment: Since you are telling mod_wsgi to use a Python virtual environment, have you verified that mod_wsgi is actually compiled for the same Python version? http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use Have you tried adding debug statements in your code to verify it is called?